# Initializing an Angular Directive in JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive in my template. It's working great:

```
<ul class="activity-stream">
    <my-activity-stream-item ng-repeat="activity in vm.activities" activity="activity"></my-activity-stream-item>
</ul>
```

I'd basically like to include the same HTML in that template as a popup in a Leaflet Map, but I have no idea how to create that in code. Here's what I tried:

```
for (i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
  var activity = activities[i];
  var marker = L.marker([activity.location.lat, activity.location.lng]);
  marker.type = activity.type;
  marker.bindPopup( '<my-activity-stream-item activity="activity"></my-activity-stream-item>' );
  marker.addTo( map );
}
```

I didn't really expect that to work, I feel like I have to pass the scope in somehow... but I'm at a complete loss as to how to do it.

```
var app = angular.module('myPortal');

app.factory('TemplateService', TemplateService);
app.directive('myActivityStreamItem', myActivityStreamItem);

function myActivityStreamItem( $compile, TemplateService ) {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: linker,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
          activity: '='
      }
  };

  function linker(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.rootDirectory = 'images/';

    TemplateService.getTemplate( 'activity-' + scope.activity.type ).then(function(response) {
      element.html( response.data );
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    });
  }
}

function TemplateService( $http ) {
  return {
    getTemplate: getTemplate
  };

  function getTemplate( templateName ) {
    return $http.get('/templates/' + templateName + '.html');
  }
}
```

(Note - I've only been using Angular for about a week, so please let me know if you think I've done this completely wrong)

**EDIT:** I took Chandermani's advice and switched my directive to an `ngInclude`:

```
<ul class="activity-stream">
    <li ng-repeat="activity in vm.activities" ng-include="'/templates/activity-' + activity.type + '.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

This works great! I also tried to use Josh's advice to compile the HTML in JavaScript, however I'm not quite there...

```
var link = $compile('<li ng-include="\'/templates/activity-' + activity.type + '.html\'"></li>');
var newScope = $rootScope.$new();
newScope.activity = activity;
var html = link( newScope );
marker.bindPopup( html[0] );
```

This results in the popup appearing, but the HTML contained within the popup is a comment: `<!-- ngInclude: '/templates/activity-incident.html' -->`

Do I have to pass it the activity in the `li` somehow?

**Edit 2:** Got it! As noted in [Issue #4505](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4505), you need to wrap the snippet in something, so I wrapped my `ngInclude` in a `div`:

```
var link = $compile( '<div><ng-include src="\'/templates/activity-incident.html\'"></ng-include></div>' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you want to add raw HTML to the page and have Angular process it, you need to use the [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) service.

Calling `$compile` on a template will return a linking function which can then be used to bind a scope object to.

```
var link = $compile('<span>{{someObj}}</span>');
```

Linking that function to a `scope` object will result in an element that can then be appended into the DOM.

```
//Or the scope provided by a directive, etc...
var newScope = $rootScope.$new();

var elem = link(newScope);

//Could also be the element provided by directive
$('someSelector').append(elem);
```

That's the basic flow you need to be able to tell Angular to process your DOM element. Usually this is done via a directive, and that's probably what you need in this case as well.

Comment: Okay, I've been trying to get the `$compile` to work, but I was having trouble with the scope. I'll give this a shot...

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell based on the context I'm seeing in your question. I can't quite tell how your loop to add marker popups relates the the original directive you have shown.

Comment: I'm putting the 'activities' in a list on the page, and also want the same information to be displayed when you click a map marker, if that makes sense? So, currently they're being displayed on the page, but I can't get them to display on the map.

Comment: So, I took Chandermani's advice and switched to an ngInclude, rather than a directive, and your code's got me most of the way there... but all I'm getting in the view is this comment: `<!-- ngInclude: '/templates/activity-incident.html' -->` (which is doubly strange because I'm passing the `$compile` this: `'<li ng-include="\'/templates/activity-incident.html\'"></li>'`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure i have understood your problem, but what you can do is to use `ng-include` directive and it can take a template expression to dynamically load a template. Something like:

```
<ul class="activity-stream">
    <li ng-repeat="activity in vm.activities" ng-include="'/templates/activity-' + activity.type + '.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

You may not require a directive here.

Comment: Holy crap! You just simplified my code a whole lot! I figured there had to be an easier way to do what I was doing, but couldn't find it.